# Enviar ao banco de dados - Adicionar/Remover/JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Pesquisando, consegui achar um script para criar e remover campos.

Link [Adicionar e Remover campos com Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34770/adicionar-e-remover-campos-com-javascript)

Minha dúvida agora, é como enviar esses dados ao banco de dados, para uma futura consulta e exibição?

Minha [versão:](http://jsfiddle.net/oj1555vp/1/)

```js
$(function () {
    var divContent = $('#formulario');
    var botaoAdicionar = $('a[data-id="1"]');
    var i = 1;

    //Ao clicar em adicionar ele cria uma linha com novos campos
    $(botaoAdicionar).click(function () {
        $('<div class="conteudoIndividual"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-5"><div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;"><label class="control-label">Veículo</label><select name="veiculo[]" id="" class="form-control"><option value="S">Sim</option><option value="N">Não</option></select></div></div><div class="col-xs-2"><div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;"><label class="control-label">Valor</label><input name="veiculoValor[]" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="" required></div></div></div><a href="#" class="linkRemover">- Remover Campos</a></div>').appendTo(divContent);
        $('#removehidden').remove();
        i++;
        $('<input type="hidden" name="quantidadeCampos" value="' + i + '" id="removehidden">').appendTo(divContent);
    });

    //Cliquando em remover a linha é eliminada
    $('#formulario').on('click', '.linkRemover', function () {
        $(this).parents('.conteudoIndividual').remove();
        i--;
    });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" data-id="1" id="adicionarCampo">+ adicionar campo</a>

<form action="teste.php" method="post">
    <div id="formulario">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;">
                <label class="control-label">Veículo</label>
                <select name="veiculo[]" id="" class="form-control">
                    <option value="S">Sim</option>
                    <option value="N">Não</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;">
                <label class="control-label">Valor</label>
                <input name="veiculoValor[]" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
    <input type="submit" value="Gerar Código" />
</form>
```

Comment: Editei a sua pergunta de forma a trazer o código do [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oj1555vp/) para aqui. Não sei porquê o `adicionar campo` funciona lá e no *snippet* não.

Comment: Sr @ramaral sabe como posso enviar para o BD?

Comment: O que tem no script 'teste.php'?

Comment: nada, é o próprio arquivo do html

Comment: É esse script que deve salvar no banco de dados. Você vai utilizar MySQL?

Comment: Sim Sr bd mysql.

Comment: Você já tem as tabelas criadas no MySQL?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23581/discussion-between-tiago-and-gabrieloliveira).

Comment: Ainda não pois não sei qual seria a melhor forma.
Eu estava pensando em enviar como array, isso seria o correto?

Comment: Eu criei na mão, não sei se esta certo. Na teoria essa é a melhor forma? Enviar tudo para apenas um campo na tabela http://i.imgur.com/X9Eidpn.png

Comment: Seguinte: Você precisa primeiro criar a tabela que vai receber esses valores. Com a tabela, você vai receber na página um array com esses valores do formulário. Vai percorrer cada um. Ex: foreach ($_POST['veiculo'] as $key=>$value){mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (veiculo, veiculoValor) VALUES ('$value', '{$_POST['veiculoValor'][$key]}');}

Comment: Mas isso vai criar vários campos, correto? Eu estava pensando em criar um unico campo para receber os dados via array, como nessa imagem que criei na mão http://i.imgur.com/X9Eidpn.png

Comment: @gabrieloliveira viu o que escrevi?

Comment: Estou no bate-papo, abre lá.

Comment: Como faço o foreach desses dados? $veiculo = a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:1:"S";i:1;s:1:"S";}i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:6:"350.00";i:1;s:6:"400.00";}}

Comment: Não funciona foreach($veiculo as $key => $val){
   echo "$val";
  }