# Clonar <select> jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, clone

Galera, sou iniciante e estou tendo dificuldades em fazer funcionar este código que usei à partir de outro tópico daqui mesmo ([Adicionar e Remover campos com Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34770/adicionar-e-remover-campos-com-javascript)).

Aqui ele não rodou, mas em meu localhost ele até clona o trecho pedido, mas não mostra apenas **select**.

Confirmo que o **select** também é clonado pelo *"Inspecionar elemento"* do navegador.

Por favor, apontem onde estou cometendo o erro, ou se está faltando fazer alguma coisa.

Grato, desde já.

```js
$(function() {
  var divContent = $('#materialInst');
  var botaoAdicionar = $('a[data-id="1"]');
  var i = 1;

  //Ao clicar em adicionar ele cria uma linha com novos campos
  $(botaoAdicionar).click(function() {
    $('<div class="conteudoIndividual"><div><input type="number" name="qitem0' + i + '" id="qitem0"><label for="qitem0">Quantidade</label></div><div><select id="item0" name="item0' + i + '"><option value="" disabled selected>Material</option><option value="1">item1</option><option value="2">item2</option><option value="3">item3</option></select></div><div><input disabled type="number" name="vitem0' + i + '" id="item0"><label for="vitem0">Valor unitário R$</label></div><div><input disabled type="number" name="vtitem0' + i + '" id="vtitem0"><label for="vtitem0">Valor total R$</label></div></div>').appendTo(divContent);
    $('#removehidden').remove();
    i++;
    $('<input type="hidden" name="quantidadeCampos" value="' + i + '" id="removehidden">').appendTo(divContent);
  });

  //Cliquando em remover a linha é eliminada
  $('#materialInst').on('click', '.linkRemover', function() {
    $(this).parents('.conteudoIndividual').remove();
    i--;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="materialInst">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" name="qitem0" id="qitem0">
      <label for="qitem0">Quantidade</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="item0" name="item0">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Material</option>
                <option value="1">item1</option>
                <option value="2">item2</option>
                <option value="3">item3</option>
          </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input disabled type="number" name="vitem0" id="item0">
      <label for="vitem0">Valor unitário R$</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input disabled type="number" name="vtitem0" id="vtitem0">
      <label for="vtitem0">Valor total R$</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="adicionar" data-id="1">Clonar</a>
```

**Solução:**
Era o framework(materialize).
Eu retirei todas as classes e funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OBS: incluído link de remover.

Caso não haja falta de inclusão da biblioteca jquery.min.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

talvez esteja errando na ordem de colocação, correto `Biblioteca, JavaScript e HTML`.

A ordem é como segue:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
$(function () {
    var divContent = $('#materialInst');
    var botaoAdicionar = $('a[data-id="1"]');
    var i = 1;

    //Ao clicar em adicionar ele cria uma linha com novos campos
    $(botaoAdicionar).click(function () {


        $('<div class="conteudoIndividual"><div><input type="number" name="qitem0' + i + '" id="qitem0"><label for="qitem0">Quantidade</label></div><div><select id="item0" name="item0' + i + '"><option value="" disabled selected>Material</option><option value="1">item1</option><option value="2">item2</option><option value="3">item3</option></select><a href="#" class="linkRemover"> Remover Campos</a></div><div><input disabled type="number" name="vitem0' + i + '" id="item0"><label for="vitem0">Valor unitário R$</label></div><div><input disabled type="number" name="vtitem0' + i + '" id="vtitem0"><label for="vtitem0">Valor total R$</label></div></div>').appendTo(divContent);

        $('#removehidden').remove();
        i++;
        $('<input type="hidden" name="quantidadeCampos" value="' + i + '" id="removehidden">').appendTo(divContent);
    });

    //Cliquando em remover a linha é eliminada
    $('#materialInst').on('click', '.linkRemover', function () {
        $(this).parents('.conteudoIndividual').remove();
        i--;
    });
});
//-->
</script>


<div id="materialInst">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" name="qitem0" id="qitem0">
      <label for="qitem0">Quantidade</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="item0" name="item0">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Material</option>
                <option value="1">item1</option>
                <option value="2">item2</option>
                <option value="3">item3</option>
                </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input disabled type="number" name="vitem0" id="item0">
      <label for="vitem0">Valor unitário R$</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input disabled type="number" name="vtitem0" id="vtitem0">
      <label for="vtitem0">Valor total R$</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="adicionar" data-id="1">Clonar</a>
```

**No trecho JavaScript/HTML/CSS das respostas, conforme abaixo mostrado, há uma inversão na colocação.** `JavaScript, Biblioteca e HTML`

> dessa forma, publicando a aplicação no servidor, não vai funcionar!

```js
 $(function () {
     var divContent = $('#materialInst');
     var botaoAdicionar = $('a[data-id="1"]');
     var i = 1;
 
     //Ao clicar em adicionar ele cria uma linha com novos campos
     $(botaoAdicionar).click(function () {
        
     
         $('<div class="conteudoIndividual"><div><input type="number" name="qitem0' + i + '" id="qitem0"><label for="qitem0">Quantidade</label></div><div><select id="item0" name="item0' + i + '"><option value="" disabled selected>Material</option><option value="1">item1</option><option value="2">item2</option><option value="3">item3</option></select><a href="#" class="linkRemover"> Remover Campos</a></div><div><input disabled type="number" name="vitem0' + i + '" id="item0"><label for="vitem0">Valor unitário R$</label></div><div><input disabled type="number" name="vtitem0' + i + '" id="vtitem0"><label for="vtitem0">Valor total R$</label></div></div>').appendTo(divContent);
 
         $('#removehidden').remove();
         i++;
         $('<input type="hidden" name="quantidadeCampos" value="' + i + '" id="removehidden">').appendTo(divContent);
     });
 
     //Cliquando em remover a linha é eliminada
     $('#materialInst').on('click', '.linkRemover', function () {
         $(this).parents('.conteudoIndividual').remove();
         i--;
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="materialInst">
   <div>
     <div>
       <input type="number" name="qitem0" id="qitem0">
       <label for="qitem0">Quantidade</label>
     </div>
     <div>
       <select id="item0" name="item0">
                 <option value="" disabled selected>Material</option>
                 <option value="1">item1</option>
                 <option value="2">item2</option>
                 <option value="3">item3</option>
           </select>
     </div>
     <div>
       <input disabled type="number" name="vitem0" id="item0">
       <label for="vitem0">Valor unitário R$</label>
     </div>
     <div>
       <input disabled type="number" name="vtitem0" id="vtitem0">
       <label for="vtitem0">Valor total R$</label>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <a href="#" id="adicionar" data-id="1">Clonar</a>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas correções @Leo.
Eu testei e em um arquivo de testes, separado do formulário completo funciona corretamente. 
Já dentro do arquivo original, ele torna o **select** hidden.
Estou usando um framework para a personalização, será que isso estaria interferindo?

Comment: Era o framework(materialize).
Eu retirei todas as classes e funcionou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Seria isso? a falta do `jQuery`? Se não for, eu não entendi qual seu problema.

```js
$(function() {
  var divContent = $('#materialInst');
  var botaoAdicionar = $('a[data-id="1"]');
  var i = 1;

  //Ao clicar em adicionar ele cria uma linha com novos campos
  $(botaoAdicionar).click(function() {
    $('<div class="conteudoIndividual"><div><input type="number" name="qitem0' + i + '" id="qitem0"><label for="qitem0">Quantidade</label></div><div><select id="item0" name="item0' + i + '"><option value="" disabled selected>Material</option><option value="1">item1</option><option value="2">item2</option><option value="3">item3</option></select></div><div><input disabled type="number" name="vitem0' + i + '" id="item0"><label for="vitem0">Valor unitário R$</label></div><div><input disabled type="number" name="vtitem0' + i + '" id="vtitem0"><label for="vtitem0">Valor total R$</label></div></div>').appendTo(divContent);
    $('#removehidden').remove();
    i++;
    $('<input type="hidden" name="quantidadeCampos" value="' + i + '" id="removehidden">').appendTo(divContent);
  });

  //Cliquando em remover a linha é eliminada
  $('#materialInst').on('click', '.linkRemover', function() {
    $(this).parents('.conteudoIndividual').remove();
    i--;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="materialInst">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" name="qitem0" id="qitem0">
      <label for="qitem0">Quantidade</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="item0" name="item0">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Material</option>
                <option value="1">item1</option>
                <option value="2">item2</option>
                <option value="3">item3</option>
          </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input disabled type="number" name="vitem0" id="item0">
      <label for="vitem0">Valor unitário R$</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input disabled type="number" name="vtitem0" id="vtitem0">
      <label for="vtitem0">Valor total R$</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="adicionar" data-id="1">Clonar</a>
```

Comment: Na verdade não @rafael. Esta foi uma falha minha, foi minha primeira publicação aqui, então peço desculpas.
Minha dúvida é sobre o select, pois em meu local host ele fica hidden após clonar.

Comment: Era o framework(materialize).
Eu retirei todas as classes e funcionou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Sei que o tópico é antigo, mas acho que é válido deixar outra solução pra quem precisar:
Tive esse problema com o mesmo código, então procurei por alguma solução que não precisasse tirar as classes do Materialize. Basta colocar isso: `$('select').material_select();` após a linha do appendTo.

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar conosco Bruno.
Vou testar numa futura oportunidade.